# extracting only hostname from a file

Tags: linux, awk, grep, redhat

I am trying to extract only the hostname and command status in that hostname but not able to find useful grep options to do this. The file format is as follows

```
server1


bash: adinfo: command not found
```

I am trying to use grep/sed in a way that it only gives me the hostname and the command output of adinfo command. So for this what I have tried

```
more file3 |grep 'com.*nd'

bash: adinfo: command not found
bash: adinfo: command not found
```

So I partially get the output but not the server name listed above. Ideally it should list server name and that command output.

Any help is appreciated.

```
more file3 |grep 'com.*nd'
```

So to clarify, I have a big file that contains this content:

```
server1

Local host name:   server1
Joined to domain:  domain.com
Joined as:         server1.domain.com
Pre-win2K name:    server1
Current DC:        domain.com
Preferred site:    Datacenter
Zone:              servers Zone
Last password set: 2022-03-11 02:23:55 EST
CentrifyDC mode:   connected
Licensed Features: Enabled

server2

bash: adinfo: command not found
```

and I only want to see where 'adinfo' command cannot be ran, along with the server name. I can narrow down to

```
# more file3 |grep -e 'Loc.*me' -e 'Cen.*de'
Local host name:   server1
CentrifyDC mode:   connected
```

but not the other way around where I can only see the server where the adinfo doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) and [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) like so:

```
grep -P '\S' infile | grep -P -B1 '^bash: adinfo' | paste - - > outfile
```

`grep -P '\S' infile` : select the non-empty files in the input file.
`grep -P -B1 '^bash: adinfo'` : select lines that start with `bash: adinfo`.
`paste - -` : join every 2 lines into a single line.

Comment: Thanks Timur, I tried using command with the edits but only got partial output to what I was looking. I am trying to tweak the output to only what I want to see.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This code works however, it only finds the first entry with command not found, along with the server name but not other lines if there are more servers with command not found.

Comment: Please edit you question and include an example of more than 1 entry with command not found. In my tests, it worked, probably your input looks different.

Comment: I am able to get the output various option listed above and pretty much all of them work. I was wondering if there is way to grep for multiple keywords instead of one. For example if I am grepping for adinfo as a keyword, can I also grep another keyword, resolve. I know I can always repeat the same command and grep for the keywords but not sure if there is away to run the command but get two results for it, instead of one keyword.

Comment: IIUC, this should work: `grep -P '\S' infile | grep -P -B1 '^bash: (adinfo|resolve)' | paste - - > outfile`. Otherwise, I recommend posting this as a separate question. This will make your new question more visible. Make sure to add examples of the input with both of the keywords.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F': *' '
    NF==1{
        server = $1
    }
    /^Local host name/ || /^CentrifyDC mode:/ {
        a[i+=1] = $2
    }
    i==2{
        printf "%s - hostname: %s, mode: %s\n", server, a[1], a[2]
        i=0
    }
    /^bash: adinfo:/{
        printf "%s - %s \n", server, $0
    }
' file

server1 - hostname: server1, mode: connected
server2 - bash: adinfo: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks ufopilot, this script works and gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said "I only want to see where 'adinfo' command cannot be ran, along with the server name" - using any awk:

```
$ awk '/bash: adinfo:/{print prev ORS $0} NF{prev=$0}' file
server2
bash: adinfo: command not found
```

Comment: This code with awk works! Thanks so much. Now would have to try this on a file that contains 340+ servers and see what happens but for now I don't see any issues why it should fail.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk 'NF==1 {f=$1} /adinfo/ {print f,$0}' file
server2 bash: adinfo: command not found
```

`NF==1 f=$1}`   if there are one filed on the line, assume its the server name and save it in variable `f`
`/adinfo/ {print f,$0}` if line contains adinfo, print the server name in variable f with the adinfo information

Comment: Yes, this code works now I will try this on a larger file with 300+ servers and see what it can find with "command not found" option. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
server1

Local host name:   server1
Joined to domain:  domain.com
Joined as:         server1.domain.com
Pre-win2K name:    server1
Current DC:        domain.com
Preferred site:    Datacenter
Zone:              servers Zone
Last password set: 2022-03-11 02:23:55 EST
CentrifyDC mode:   connected
Licensed Features: Enabled

server2

bash: adinfo: command not found
```

then

```
sed -n '/adinfo/{G;p};/./h' file.txt
```

gives output

```
bash: adinfo: command not found 
server2
```

Explanation: `-n` turns off default printing, for lines which does contain `adinfo` append newline and hold content (`G`) then print (`p`), for lines with at least 1 characters, put content into hold space (`.`). Observe that names do appear *after* command results.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after so many trials. Thanks all for your help!

awk 'NF==1 {f=$1} /adinfo|any|resolve/ {print f,$0}'